# Scatter plot with ggplot2 colored by specific dates interval in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, as.date

I'm trying to assign different colors to the scatterplot based on their dates, more specifically the year.
This is how my dataset looks like:

```
> dput(head(CORt_r100_stack_join_fspec,10))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16779, 16834, 16884, 16924, 
16973, 16997, 17031, 17184, 17214, 17254), class = "Date"), meanNDVIN_int = c(0.677501157246889, 
0.632728796482024, 0.578636981692124, 0.547002029242488, 0.632635423362751, 
NA, 0.699596252720458, 0.670059391804396, 0.643347941166436, 
0.674034259709311), meanNDVIW_int = c(0.784142418592418, 0.652437451242156, 
0.648319814752948, 0.593432266488189, 0.767890365415717, NA, 
0.779249089832163, 0.71974944410843, 0.715777992826006, 0.685045115352089
), meanNDVIE_int = c(0.703614512017928, 0.701963337684803, 0.488628353756438, 
0.631309466083632, 0.781589421376217, NA, 0.799663418920722, 
0.78910564747191, 0.710962969930836, 0.715644011856453), meanNDVINr_int_f = c(0.677501157246889, 
0.632728796482024, 0.578636981692124, 0.547002029242488, 0.632635423362751, 
0.687343078509066, 0.699596252720458, 0.670059391804396, 0.643347941166436, 
0.674034259709311), meanNDVIWr_int_f = c(0.784142418592418, 0.652437451242156, 
0.648319814752948, 0.593432266488189, 0.767890365415717, 0.749505859407419, 
0.779249089832163, 0.71974944410843, 0.715777992826006, 0.685045115352089
), meanNDVIEr_int_f = c(0.703614512017928, 0.701963337684803, 
0.488628353756438, 0.631309466083632, 0.781589421376217, 0.625916155640988, 
0.799663418920722, 0.78910564747191, 0.710962969930836, 0.715644011856453
), NDVI_N = c(0.17221248, 0.644239685, 0.57222623, 0.558666635, 
0.51654034, 0.42053949, 0.396706695, 0.641767447, 0.641008268, 
0.662841949), NDVI_W = c(0.08182944, 0.69112807, 0.637699375, 
0.629429605, 0.658829525, 0.60621678, 0.57186129, 0.72636742, 
0.724193596, 0.738424976), NDVI_E = c(0.17135712, 0.659222803, 
0.58665977, 0.573081253, 0.533498035, 0.437643585, 0.412841468, 
0.652057206, 0.651854988, 0.670345511), NDVI_U = c(0.40520304, 
0.578414833, 0.455746833, 0.428289893, 0.208847548, 0, 0, 0.475193691, 
0.478691084, 0.505043773)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've been plotting `meanNDVIN_int` against `NDVI_N` using this code:

```
ggplot(CORt_r100_join_fspec_2NDVIday,aes(x=NDVI_N)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=meanNDVIN_int), colour="red")
  theme_bw()+
  ylab("meanNDVIN_int")+
  xlab("NDVI_N")
```

Now I want to color each point differently (no matter the color) based on their year, 2015, 2016, and 2017.
I've used the `scale_color_manual` function to introduce the dates but no success so far.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative where you `substring` the first 4 characters from `Date` in `color`

```
df
ggplot(df,aes(x=NDVI_N)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=meanNDVIN_int, color=substring(Date,1,4))) +
  labs(color="Year")+
theme_bw()+
  ylab("meanNDVIN_int")+
  xlab("NDVI_N")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I created a `year` variable with `lubridate` and stored it as`factor` for `discrete` colouring. You were just missing moving `color` inside the `aes()` to color it by `year`.

```
# Add year Variable;
CORt_r100_stack_join_fspec <- CORt_r100_stack_join_fspec %>% mutate(
        year = as.factor(lubridate::year(Date))
)


# Plot;
ggplot(CORt_r100_stack_join_fspec,aes(x=NDVI_N)) + 
        geom_point(aes(y=meanNDVIN_int, color = year)) +
        theme_bw() +
        ylab("meanNDVIN_int")+
        xlab("NDVI_N")
```

[image]

**Note:** The `data` you provided, and named is not the same as in your `plot`-call. So I changed `CORt_r100_join_fspec_2NDVIday` to `CORt_r100_join_fspec_2NDVIday` to make the `plot` and `mutate` function properly.